# WebDriverIO: browser.pause does not working

Tags: webdriver-io

I have used browser.sleep in protractor to hold the execution for a particular amount of time. In similar way I have tried the browser.pause in WebDriverIO. But it is not pausing for the given amount of time.

Even for [browser pause](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/pause.html) I referred the WebDriverIO official documentation, there also the same thing is given

**Step Definition Code:**

```
Given(/^Verify the title of Salesforce web page$/,function(){
    browser.url('https://login.salesforce.com/');
    browser.pause(10000);
});
```

I use async mode in the configuration

WebDriverIO Version: ^5.22.4

**wdio.config.js**

```
exports.config = {
    //
    // ====================
    // Runner Configuration
    // ====================
    //
    // WebdriverIO allows it to run your tests in arbitrary locations (e.g. locally or
    // on a remote machine).
    runner: 'local',
    //
    // Override default path ('/wd/hub') for chromedriver service.
    path: '/',
    //
    // ==================
    // Specify Test Files
    // ==================
    // Define which test specs should run. The pattern is relative to the directory
    // from which `wdio` was called. Notice that, if you are calling `wdio` from an
    // NPM script (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) then the current working
    // directory is where your package.json resides, so `wdio` will be called from there.
    //
    specs: [
        './test/features/*.feature'
    ],
    // Patterns to exclude.
    exclude: [
        // 'path/to/excluded/files'
    ],
    //
    // ============
    // Capabilities
    // ============
    // Define your capabilities here. WebdriverIO can run multiple capabilities at the same
    // time. Depending on the number of capabilities, WebdriverIO launches several test
    // sessions. Within your capabilities you can overwrite the spec and exclude options in
    // order to group specific specs to a specific capability.
    //
    // First, you can define how many instances should be started at the same time. Let's
    // say you have 3 different capabilities (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) and you have
    // set maxInstances to 1; wdio will spawn 3 processes. Therefore, if you have 10 spec
    // files and you set maxInstances to 10, all spec files will get tested at the same time
    // and 30 processes will get spawned. The property handles how many capabilities
    // from the same test should run tests.
    //
    maxInstances: 10,
    //
    // If you have trouble getting all important capabilities together, check out the
    // Sauce Labs platform configurator - a great tool to configure your capabilities:
    // https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/platforms-configurator
    //
    capabilities: [{

        // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
        // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
        // 5 instances get started at a time.
        maxInstances: 5,
        //
        browserName: 'chrome',
        // If outputDir is provided WebdriverIO can capture driver session logs
        // it is possible to configure which logTypes to include/exclude.
        // excludeDriverLogs: ['*'], // pass '*' to exclude all driver session logs
        // excludeDriverLogs: ['bugreport', 'server'],
    }],
    //
    // ===================
    // Test Configurations
    // ===================
    // Define all options that are relevant for the WebdriverIO instance here
    //
    // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
    logLevel: 'info',
    //
    // Set specific log levels per logger
    // loggers:
    // - webdriver, webdriverio
    // - @wdio/applitools-service, @wdio/browserstack-service, @wdio/devtools-service, @wdio/sauce-service
    // - @wdio/mocha-framework, @wdio/jasmine-framework
    // - @wdio/local-runner, @wdio/lambda-runner
    // - @wdio/sumologic-reporter
    // - @wdio/cli, @wdio/config, @wdio/sync, @wdio/utils
    // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
    // logLevels: {
    //     webdriver: 'info',
    //     '@wdio/applitools-service': 'info'
    // },
    //
    // If you only want to run your tests until a specific amount of tests have failed use
    // bail (default is 0 - don't bail, run all tests).
    bail: 0,
    //
    // Set a base URL in order to shorten url command calls. If your `url` parameter starts
    // with `/`, the base url gets prepended, not including the path portion of your baseUrl.
    // If your `url` parameter starts without a scheme or `/` (like `some/path`), the base url
    // gets prepended directly.
    baseUrl: 'https://login.salesforce.com/',
    //
    // Default timeout for all waitFor* commands.
    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    //
    // Default timeout in milliseconds for request
    // if browser driver or grid doesn't send response
    connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
    //
    // Default request retries count
    connectionRetryCount: 0,
    //
    // Test runner services
    // Services take over a specific job you don't want to take care of. They enhance
    // your test setup with almost no effort. Unlike plugins, they don't add new
    // commands. Instead, they hook themselves up into the test process.
    services: ['chromedriver','firefox-profile'],

    // Framework you want to run your specs with.
    // The following are supported: Mocha, Jasmine, and Cucumber
    // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/frameworks.html
    //
    // Make sure you have the wdio adapter package for the specific framework installed
    // before running any tests.
    framework: 'cucumber',
    //
    // The number of times to retry the entire specfile when it fails as a whole
    // specFileRetries: 1,
    //
    // Test reporter for stdout.
    // The only one supported by default is 'dot'
    // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/dot-reporter.html
    reporters: ['spec',['allure', {
        outputDir: 'allure-results',
        disableWebdriverStepsReporting: true,
        disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: false,
        useCucumberStepReporter:true
    }]],
    // If you are using Cucumber you need to specify the location of your step definitions.
    cucumberOpts: {
        require: ['./built/**/*.js'],        // <string[]> (file/dir) require files before executing features
        backtrace: false,   // <boolean> show full backtrace for errors
        requireModule: [],  // <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
        dryRun: false,      // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
        failFast: false,    // <boolean> abort the run on first failure
        format: ['pretty'], // <string[]> (type[:path]) specify the output format, optionally supply PATH to redirect formatter output (repeatable)
        colors: true,       // <boolean> disable colors in formatter output
        snippets: true,     // <boolean> hide step definition snippets for pending steps
        source: true,       // <boolean> hide source uris
        profile: [],        // <string[]> (name) specify the profile to use
        strict: false,      // <boolean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps
        tagExpression: '',  // <string> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression
        timeout: 60000,     // <number> timeout for step definitions
        ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false, // <boolean> Enable this config to treat undefined definitions as warnings.
    },

    //
    // =====
    // Hooks
    // =====
    // WebdriverIO provides several hooks you can use to interfere with the test process in order to enhance
    // it and to build services around it. You can either apply a single function or an array of
    // methods to it. If one of them returns with a promise, WebdriverIO will wait until that promise got
    // resolved to continue.
    /**
     * Gets executed once before all workers get launched.
     * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     */
    // onPrepare: function (config, capabilities) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed just before initialising the webdriver session and test framework. It allows you
     * to manipulate configurations depending on the capability or spec.
     * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
     */
    // beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed before test execution begins. At this point you can access to all global
     * variables like `browser`. It is the perfect place to define custom commands.
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
     */
    before: function (_capabilities) {
           // =================
        // Assertion Library
        // =================
        const chai    = require('chai');
        global.expect = chai.expect;
        global.assert = chai.assert;
        global.should = chai.should();
        require('ts-node').register({ files: true });
    },
    /**
     * Runs before a WebdriverIO command gets executed.
     * @param {String} commandName hook command name
     * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
     */
    // beforeCommand: function (commandName, args) {
    // },
    /**
     * Runs before a Cucumber feature
     */
    beforeFeature: function (uri, feature, scenarios) {
        scenarioCounter = 0;
    },
    /**
     * Runs before a Cucumber scenario
     */
    // beforeScenario: function (uri, feature, scenario, sourceLocation) {
    // },
    /**
     * Runs before a Cucumber step
     */
    // beforeStep: function (uri, feature, stepData, context) {
    // },
    /**
     * Runs after a Cucumber step
     */
    afterStep: function (uri, feature, { error, result, duration, passed }, stepData, context) {
        if (error !== undefined) {
            browser.takeScreenshot();
        }
    },
    /**
     * Runs after a Cucumber scenario
     */
    afterScenario: function (uri, feature, scenario, result, sourceLocation) {
        scenarioCounter += 1;
        addArgument('Scenario #', scenarioCounter);
    },
    /**
     * Runs after a Cucumber feature
     */
    // afterFeature: function (uri, feature, scenarios) {
    // },

    /**
     * Runs after a WebdriverIO command gets executed
     * @param {String} commandName hook command name
     * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
     * @param {Number} result 0 - command success, 1 - command error
     * @param {Object} error error object if any
     */
    // afterCommand: function (commandName, args, result, error) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed after all tests are done. You still have access to all global variables from
     * the test.
     * @param {Number} result 0 - test pass, 1 - test fail
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
     */
    // after: function (result, capabilities, specs) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed right after terminating the webdriver session.
     * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
     */
    // afterSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed after all workers got shut down and the process is about to exit. An error
     * thrown in the onComplete hook will result in the test run failing.
     * @param {Object} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail
     * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {<Object>} results object containing test results
     */
    // onComplete: function(exitCode, config, capabilities, results) {
    // },
    /**
    * Gets executed when a refresh happens.
    * @param {String} oldSessionId session ID of the old session
    * @param {String} newSessionId session ID of the new session
    */
    //onReload: function(oldSessionId, newSessionId) {
    //}
}
```

Comment: Could you share what is version you are using and your config file?

Comment: @Raju I have edited the question and added the version, config file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since, it was an *async* mode in WebDriverIO, have to add the **await** in both of the lines as below.

```
Given(/^Verify the title of Salesforce web page$/, async function(){
    await browser.url('https://login.salesforce.com/');
    await browser.pause(10000);
});
```

Comment: Great to see you got it working, isnt this exactly what I proposed when I said above to add this too `await browser.url('https://login.salesforce.com/');` I can amend my initial answer, would that work for you?

Comment: Sure,I thought it was to add the await only on the browser.url not on the pause

Comment: No worries, good you got it working, I should have updated at that time for better clarity. Anyways, updated now, you can approve if happy with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Might be worthy trying async/await as below:

```
Given(/^Verify the title of Salesforce web page$/, async function(){
    await browser.url('https://login.salesforce.com/');
    await browser.pause(10000);
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I have tried the above one and still it is not working

Comment: Sorry... did not work for you. I supposed you tried also adding await here as well `await browser.url('https://login.salesforce.com/');` ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case someone had globally activated fake timers (`jest.useFakeTimers()`).

For now, in my End to end tests, I'm just switching back to real timers (`jest.useRealTimers()`).